# How to do text wrapping inside a table with auto layout

Tags: html, css, reactjs, dom

I have a table with auto layout which has strings inside <td> and some of them may be long so i would prefer to wrap them to avoid too long horizontal display.  I tried both apply the style to <td> or put <div> around the elements for this but couldn't get it to work properly.  I observed the following:

1. In order to have any text wrapping at all, the *white-space* property has to be set to one of its wrapping values such as *pre-wrap*, *normal*, *pre-line*, etc.  If instead *white-space* is set to any non-wrapping value such as *pre*, wrapping doesn't happen no matter what values i use for *overflow-wrap* or *break-word* properties.  Even if i set *max-width*, the text just overflows.
2. If I set *white-space* to a wrapping value, such as *pre-wrap*, the wrapping happens but it wraps too much: I guess it tries to auto-size the column to its minimum possible width and then wraps accordingly.  E.g. if the column header has only 2 characters, it wraps after each 2 characters and i see my strings broken into multiple lines 2-character long, which certainly does not look good.  Note that my table does have a lot of columns, so maybe that's why it chooses to auto-size column width like this.

What I would prefer is to simply wrap after certain width is reached, but not before, e.g. start wrapping if it exceeds 30 characters.  Is there a way to do this (short of breaking strings manually in code)?  Note that i tried *max-width* but it didn't work as i mentioned above (depending on *white-space* value, it either overflows or starts wrapping at min possible width).

The only thing that did work, sort of, is setting *min-width* (together with the wrapping value of *white-space* property, in which case it didn't size the column or wrap to smaller than that value.  However, this is not exactly what I want: some column values may be short and i don't want to create unnecessary space in this case.  If the column values are short (such that no wrapping is needed) i would prefer to size to content (btw, i tried using *min-content* and *fit-content*, but it didn't work, still the same behavior).

Note that for an unrelated reason, setting *table-layout* to *fixed* is not an option for me.

Comment: could you use `display: grid` to make the table instead?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have to use this particular component and cannot change its style, can only change the content of the table cells.